# Read the value of a register in arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, shift-register, windows

I want to read the value of the register (8-bit). In particular I want to read the values of:

1. The Timer/Counter - TCNT0 ( **Adress** 0x26 (0x46) )
2. The output compare registers - OCR0A and OCR0B.

Is there a way to read them with the Arduino program?

Comment: How about just using them in your program? You can use the register names directly

Comment: @chrisl So is the output of Serial.print(TCNT0, BIN) the current value (in binary) of the register?

Comment: Yes, that should work. You see much code on the web, where timers are configured by directly writing to the registers. You can try it. Write a value to a register and read it back. Though, if you are using the Arduino core, the timer0 counter will change, because it is used for `millis()` and siblings. You can try it with a currently disabled timer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert my comments to an answer:

You can use the register names directly. They are defined in the boards/chips core. To read them, simply use the names in your calculations. Write to the registers by setting the value of the registers name (like a variable: `TCNT0 = 0;`). Be sure to look into the datasheet, to check the behavior of that register.

Comment: As noted, do check the datasheet -- some register flags are cleared (zeroed) by writing a 1 to them.